# progressbar in a thread does not update its UI until the work was done in the main thread

Tags: java, swing, progress-bar

i am cutting a big file into blocks, and want to display the rate of the progress.
when i click startCut Button, here is the code to execute：

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
int blockSize = (int)(getSelectedBlockSize() * 1024);
int totalBlock = Integer.parseInt(txtNumberOfBlock.getText());
byte[] buffer = new byte[blockSize];
int readBytes = in.read(buffer);
int fileIndex = 1;

class PBThread extends Thread
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            pbCompleteness.setValue(value);
            //value++; //place A
            System.out.println(value);
            if (value >= 100)
                break;
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
        }
    }
}
value = 0;
PBThread pbThread = new PBThread();
pbThread.start();
while(readBytes != -1)
{
    File file = new File(targetFilePath + fileIndex);
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    out.write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
    out.close();
    value = (int)(fileIndex / (double)totalBlock * 100);// place B
    readBytes = in.read(buffer);
    fileIndex++;
}
```

i change the value of the progressbar outside the run method at place B,the problem is that --the grogressbar only show two state: 0% and 100%.
  but, if i take away the code in place B, and change the value of the progressbar inside the run method at place A, the problem will disappear.
  i know maybe with `SwingWorker` it can be fixed easily, but i do want to know why this happen,although i change the value out the run method,when i print it out in the run method,it did changed.
  how can i fix that problem while changing value outside the run method?

Comment: Apart from the good advice you have already received.. `Thread.sleep(100);` - don't do that.  If a delay is required in a GUI (e.g. for animation), create a Swing [`Timer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The crux of the problem is that you're updating the component: `pbCompleteness` on a thread **other than the Event Dispatch Thread**.  You can remedy this using [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) from within your `run()` method; e.g.

```
AtomicInteger value = new AtomicInteger(0);
while (true) {
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      pbCompleteness.setValue(value.get());
    }
  });

  // Do some work and update value.
}
```

This will cause the `JProgressBar` to be updated (and repainted) on the Event Dispatch thread as your worker thread continues to run.  Note that in order to refer to `value` within the "inner" anonymous `Runnable` instance I have changed it to be an `AtomicInteger`.  This is also desirable as it makes it thread-safe.

Comment: just now, i gained some knowledge about Event Dispatch Thread and understand what you said, thx a lot

Comment: The problem is not that he's updating a Swing component off of the EDT -- that would cause a NPE or possibly a race condition. Since his Swing is locking up, he is calling a long running bit of code *on* the EDT, probably this part: `while(readBytes != -1) {...}`, and it needs to be in a background thread.

Comment: i have tried your method, there's still the problem, how can i show you my new code using your method?

Comment: *"how can i show you my new code"*  Edit the question (then notify the repliers in a comment to each one - so they know).

Answer (score 3):

You've got two problems here:

- You're doing long-running work in the Swing dispatcher thread, which means you're stopping it from processing events. (Try moving windows around etc - it will fail.)
- You're updating the UI from the wrong thread at point A. It sounds like you're getting away with this at the moment, but it's still a bug.

You should use `SwingWorker` or `SwingUtilities` to address both of these issues. Basically, you mustn't access the UI from a non-UI thread, and you mustn't do long-running work on a UI thread. See the [Swing concurrency tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.

Comment: i will remember what you said. and you help me a lot.thx very much

Answer (score -1):

i found a very simple way to this prob :D . you can use this code and very simlpe handel this error :).

```
int progress=0;
Random random = new Random();
while (progress < 100) {
 //Sleep for up to one second.
 try {
       Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(100));
} catch (InterruptedException ignore) {}
progress+=1;
progressBar.setValue(progress);
Rectangle progressRect = progressBar.getBounds();//important line 
progressRect.x = 0;
progressRect.y = 0;         
progressBar.paintImmediately(progressRect);//important line 
 }
```